# Optimization from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel, optimization

I am struggling with solving below optimization in R. It was easy for me to do with excel solver but I am not able to do same problem in R. I don’t have much experience in optimization in R
Problem is to assign when a particular activity should be a done over the time period. A1, A2,…, A12 are 12 activities which are done in a field. 0 stands for not assigned, 1 stands for assigned.

Constraints are -

- A2 should happen after A1 is completed, A3 should occur after A2 is complete and so on
- A3, A5, A6 - only two of these activities can happen on a particular day
- Each activity should happen in a field ( in excel solver, this constraint is defined by taking row sum equals to one

It would be a great help, if anyone can help in solving this problem. I have attached image for better understanding of this problem.
Also, please let me know if there is any site or book, rich in examples on "how to solve optimization problems in R". Thanking you in anticipation.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a small, straight MIP problem. Don't see why this would cause problems in R.

Comment: Answer for two of your constraints below. Right now I can't think of an elegant way to do the last one ("A2 should happen after A1"). Where and how is that formulated in your Excel solver?

Comment: @JanLauGe, In excel, for that constraint, I am taking `SUMPRODUCT` of each row with time (where I have created a sequence 1,2,...,12) and then difference should be `>=`1. For an example - `SUMPRODUCT(row2,timesequence) - SUMPRODUCT(row1,timesequence) >= 1`. Hope, this answers your question. Thank you!

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, Since, I don't have much experience in optimization with R, that's why I posted this question to get an answer. It would be great if you can help me in solving this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can solve your problem using the `lpSolve` package.

You will require a cost vector and constraints information. Constraint information in fed into the function in the following structure:

- `lhs`: a "left hand side" matrix of coefficients, one for each decision variable
- `dir`: a "direction", namely `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`
- `rhs`: a "right hand side" as numeric value

To build your list of constraints, I find it useful to think of each decision you could possibly take as an X (becomes a column in the `lhs` table) and each constraint you would like to define as a separate equation (becomes a row in the `lhs` table, with a corresponding value in `dir` and `rhs`, respectively)

Let us start with all possible decisions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# What are the decision variables? ----

# Which action to take
actions <- str_c('A',seq(1:12) %>% formatC(width = 2, flag = '0'))
actions
#[1] "A01" "A02" "A03" "A04" "A05" "A06" "A07" "A08" "A09" "A10" "A11" "A12"

# When to take it
timings <- str_c('T',seq(1:12) %>% formatC(width = 2, flag = '0'))
timings
#[1] "T01" "T02" "T03" "T04" "T05" "T06" "T07" "T08" "T09" "T10" "T11" "T12"

# List of all possible decisions is this:
decisions <- expand.grid(actions, timings)

# Convert it to a vector
decision_variables <- str_c(decisions[,1], '_', decisions[,2])

# You also need a cost vector. 
# We'll use a value increasing as a function of timings, 
# as this will penalize "late" actions?
cost <- rep(seq(1:length(timings)), length(actions)) %>% sort
```

Each element of `decision_variables` is one possible action (i.e. take an action at a given time. Now we can start narrowing down the options available to the solver by introducing constraints.

---

First type of constraint: Each option should only be taken once!
(This is actually your third, but I start with this as it's the simplest one)
We can formulate that like this:

```
# Create a matrix with one column per possible decision
# and one row per action (for now)
lhs <- matrix(0, 
  nrow = length(actions), 
  ncol = length(decision_variables), 
  dimnames = list(
    actions, 
    decision_variables))

# Each action should only be taken once!
for (i in 1:length(actions)) {
  # Which fields does an action occur in?
  this_action <- str_detect(colnames(lhs), actions[i])
  # Set their coefficients to 1
  lhs[i,this_action] <- 1
}
# create corresponding dir and rhs values
dir <- rep('==', length(actions))
rhs <- rep(1, length(actions))
```

You can see that we set the coefficient of all `X`'s (decisions) that contain the `action` in question to `1`. In our final solution, each `X` will take the value of either `0` or `1`. If `X` is zero, the coefficient will be irrelevant. If `X` is `1`, the coefficient will be added to the sum of the `lhs` and compared using `dir` to the `rhs` value.

Here, our constraint is that the sum of `coefficient * X == 1` for each of the constraints we just introduced. Coefficients are 1 for all possible decisions containing a given action. Ergo, a solution is only valid if any given action is only taken once.

---

Second constraint: Only two of `c('A03', 'A05', 'A06')` should co-occur on a given day.

Again, we generate one line per constraint. In this case, I think we need one constraint per day. We append the values we generate to the already existing `lhs`, `dir`, and `rhs` variables:

```
# only one of A3, A5, A6 at any given time.
# One constraint for each timestep
for (j in timings) {
  lhs <- rbind(lhs, ifelse(str_detect(decision_variables, paste0('A0[356]{1}_',j)), 1, 0))
  dir <- c(dir, '<=')
  rhs <- c(rhs, 2)
}
```

---

*Placeholder for third constraint*

---

Presto, we've formulated our problem. Now let `lpSolve` crunch the numbers!
You can feed our problem into the algorithm like this:

```
library(lpSolve)

# Run lpSolve to find best solution
solution <- lp(
  # maximise or minimise the objective function?
  direction = 'min',
  # coefficients of each variable
  objective.in = cost,
  const.mat = lhs, 
  const.dir = dir, 
  const.rhs = rhs)

# Extract the values of X for the best solution:
print(solution$solution)

# Convert it into ta matrix of the format you are familiar with
matrix(solution$solution, 
       nrow = length(timings), 
       ncol = length(actions),
       dimnames = list(actions, timings))
```

Does this do what you need?

Any questions?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. `print` solution gives me an output as vector. It would be great if you can help me reading the output. The solution that I am looking for - assigning 0,1 in the decision matrix (as shown in picture). In excel my objective function is `colSums(decision_matrix) * seq(1,12)`. It would be great if you can explain, if you are considering these things. Thank you once again!

Comment: Each value of `decision_variables` corresponds to one field in your excel table (12 by 12 table = 144 fields). The solutions vector gives you `0` or `1` for each field. Convert it to a matrix of the format you are used to, adding that to the answer now.

Comment: As for your objective function, you seem to penalize later months so that actions get taken as early as possible. We can implement that by just making the `cost` vector a numeric vector increasing over the timings. Added that as well.

Comment: Yes, now getting in matrix. This is really helpful. Only thing is left with occurrence constraint. Can we do something like `SUMPRODUCT` logic, I explained to you in above comment? Thank you!

Comment: I'll think about that a little bit more. One solution would be to hard-code every single action pair for every possible timing combination, but that seems like total overkill. I am wondering if it can be done more cleverly, maybe by modifying the cost function rather than the constraints. Perhaps somebody else has an idea?

Comment: Sure, thank for taking out time to solve this problem. I really appreciate it.