# Struggle with converting an Excel based solver solution to R

Tags: r, solver

In Excel I have created a model that I can solve with the Excel Solver (Evolutionary). Now I would like to transfer this model to R, but I am struggling on how to make this work. At its root it is an assignment problem, but not linear like the problems that I have worked with before. I hope to learn how to setup a problem like this so that I can experiment furhter on the basis of this.

I will try to explain the problem clearly.

Here is the data for the above two tables:

```
library(data.table)
OrderAssignments <- structure(list(OrderID = 1:15, OriginalResource = c("R1", "R1", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3"), NewResource = c("R2", "R3", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R1"), From = c("B", "A", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "B", "A", "B", "D", "D", "A", "C", "C"), To = c("H", "G", "F", "E", "H", "E", "H", "G", "H", "E", "H", "F", "E", "E", "E"), Qty = c(4750L, 3250L, 8500L, 8500L, 3750L, 4250L, 5500L, 4750L, 1750L, 4750L, 4000L, 2250L, 4000L, 1250L, 7500L), Fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("OrderID", "OriginalResource", "NewResource", "From", "To", "Qty", "Fixed"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))
resources <- structure(list(Resource = c("R1", "R2", "R3"), MaxQty = c(27500L, 22000L, 26125L), MaxNr = 5:7), .Names = c("Resource", "MaxQty", "MaxNr"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

My goal is to change "NewResource" so that the assignment has a lower objecrtive cost function while it is continues to play by the contraints.

I have the following constraints:

- SUM Qty per Resource <= MaxQty of Resource
- COUNT OrderID per Resource <= MaxNr of Resource
- OrderIDs cannot be split over more than one Resource.

The objective function is calculated as following:

```
objective <- [(A-B)*cost_AB] + [D * cost_D] + [C * cost_C]
```

Where:
 - cost_AB = 100
 - cost_C = 500
 - cost_D = 10000
 - (A) Unique count of [OriginalResource in combi with From] + [OriginalResource in combi with To] 
 - (B) Unique count of [NewResource in combi with From] + [NewResource in combi with To] 
 - (C) Count of OrderID where OriginalResource <> NewResource
 - (D) Count of OrderID where Fixed = TRUE and OriginalResource <> NewResource

My initial way to implement this in R is the following:

```
A <- nrow(unique(OrderAssignments, by=c("OriginalResource","From"))) + nrow(unique(OrderAssignments, by=c("OriginalResource","To")))
B <- nrow(unique(OrderAssignments, by=c("NewResource","From"))) + nrow(unique(OrderAssignments, by=c("NewResource","To")))
C <- nrow(OrderAssignments [ which(OrderAssignments$OriginalResource != OrderAssignments$NewResource)])
D <- nrow(OrderAssignments [ which(OrderAssignments$OriginalResource != OrderAssignments$NewResource & OrderAssignments$Fixed==TRUE)])
```

Based on those variables in combination with the costs function the objective function can be calculated.

My initial thought for a solution is to create a assignment matrix with Orders and Resources. However, I struggle to see how to bridge this to the objective function and therefore find a way to solve the solution in a smart way. I would appreciate if somebody can provide me some directions on creating a solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you already had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867756/6197649 ?

Comment: I believe this can be stated as a linear model so a MIP solver could be more appropriate. Heuristics not needed (at least not for data sets that are reasonable sized).